# create flash projector application which cannot be closed

Tags: flash, adobe, passwords, projector

I need to create a flash projector application which can be interacted with, but will not close unless a password is entered.

I have created the projector file which I have created a close button with a password popup, but this doesn't do anything if the user presses ALT+F4 or Escape etc..

I either need to disable these combinations of keys or find someother way of achieving this,

Any ideas ?

Cheers.

Comment: How To Irritate User Dot Com, huh?

Comment: was actually intended for display items in a shop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this (or at least come close) would be to wrap the SWF with one of the various EXE tools out there such as SWFStudio and MDM Zinc.